# Supplying to Google Maps API supported places types

Tags: api, types

We are using Google API for an app implementation. Apparently the list of supported places is limited to a group of keywords: https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types
Is there a way to add custom-made places types that Google recognizes and accepts beyond this standard list?